# error with form action

Tags: asp.net, forms, webforms, action, nullreferenceexception

I have the following C# code:

```
 AddCommentForm = string.Format("<form name=\"AddComment\" method=\"post\"  runat=\"server\" id=\"add_comment_form\"><p> TITLE:  <input type =\"text\" name=\"Title\" /></p><p> Contnt <textarea name=\"Content\" ></textarea></p><p> <button type=\"submit\">Submit!</button></p></form>");
                this.Form.Action = "ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=" + ArticleID;
```

The problem is that there is an error in the second line:

```
System.NullReferenceException was caught
```

My question is how can I this error?

And why with this code it works?

```
 <%
     this.Form.Action = "ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=" + ArticleID.ToString();
 %>
 <form name="AddComment"  method="post" runat="server">
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddCommentForm = string.Format("<form name=\"AddComment\" method=\"post\" ....
```

Above code is not valid. AddCommentForm is a HtmlForm control - not a string. Besides, you cannot create another `form` tag inside a form in ASP.Net.

```
this.Form.Action = "ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=" + ArticleID.ToString();
```

Basically, you are [Cross-Site Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx). Although it compiles, it won't work. When you get to `ViewArticle.aspx` page, you'll get an error.

**If you want a form inside ASP.Net, use iframe.**